# I'm not sure I want to be in this profession

Tags: united-kingdom

So... A while ago I started my first job as an apprentice programmer, I was more or less shoved into the IT industry by my father, I enjoy working with computers and learning how to code, but I am unhappy with the whole idea of sitting down for 9 hours a day staring at a screen. My ambition until around 6 months ago was to be a technician in the military, that dream was cut short as I learned my father would never allow me to join (16-18 requires parental consent). So I gave in and got a job as an apprentice programmer.

My question is simple; What do you advise me to do?

I hate the idea of living to work and pay bills, so life looks pretty disappointing...

If this is off topic, I am sorry, I am not used to using sites like this.

Comment: I'm sorry you're going through this, but I flagged this as too broad. I advise you to follow your own path and don't let your parents dictate your life. I would even go as far to say that if your parents threaten to cut ties because you don't fit into their selfish ideals of what they want from you, to do so promptly. Programming is not for everyone, and you only have one life.

Comment: @Lawrence Aiello Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: As stated, the real issue in your question is your relationship with your father.  Perhaps you could edit the question to re-state it to be about a workplace issue.

Comment: @GreenMatt Sorry again, not sure how else to write it

Comment: what is your age? Can't you just do this job until you are 18?

Comment: Voting to close as career advice.  Personally I would give it a go, on the understanding that as soon as I'm old enough, I'll go the army route if I don't like it (but give it a decent go).

Comment: @mhoran_psprep  The Wandering Dev Manage Thanks for the advice guys, I am 16 and will continue to do this job until I am 18

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your question, it sounds like you're under 18. That means you have a long time to work toward your dream. I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe in the UK you're not obligated to take a job and stick with it for your entire life.

You can't sign up for the military until you're 18 without parental consent. That's reasonable. Use this time to spend money and hang out with friends. Be a teenager with disposable income.

Then when you turn 18 you'll have had some time to learn about yourself outside of the military. There's a reason most countries don't allow minors in the military.

By the way, most white-collar jobs involve sitting down for 9 hours a day staring at a screen so you might what to rephrase your question to make it more general.

Comment: I have to say that is the best advice I've ever received, thanks.

Comment: I'm kind of sad to hear you say that. I hope you find some good mentors in the near future.

Comment: I would add, use the time to prep yourself for the military life and  get knowledge about the military specialty you want. Typically, the lifestyle is pretty strenuous and requires a whole lot of self-discipline. You might get in really good physical shape and do some reading on wht the lifestyle is like and talk to some actual miltary or former military. You might consider what type of technician and take classes in your spare time that will help give you a start on the knowledge you need and make it more likely that you will end up where you want to go. Think of this time as prep school.

Answer (score 4):

> I am unhappy with the whole idea of sitting down for 9 hours a day staring at a screen.

As a developer, I can tell you the reality is that in an 8 hour day, developers rarely spend 8 hours staring at their screens. Good developers don't spend all day writing code. There are meetings to be had, planning, and other tasks before a line of code is even written. We write software for people, which means we spend time interacting with the people who's jobs our code makes easier whether that be an internal employee or external customer.

For most developers the best code doesn't come out of sitting for 8 straight hours coding like a crazy code monkey. It comes from taking mental breaks here and there and refreshing yourself mentally. There will be those times when you have to focus on meeting a deadline on a mundane code task. If you don't feel you have the discipline and long-term interest to be a developer, then you should select a different perfection. But you should also get a more realistic view of the profession before concluding its strictly cranking out code 8+ hours a day non-stop.

Comment: OTOH, I dare say a good many of us would rather spend those 8 hours coding than going to meetings :-)